# Which colors are supported on Craigslist?

Tags: craigslist

There are 11 that will not render properly in craigslist even though the HEX #'s are getting input properly. They all seem to begin with or include "F".

Does anyone have any clue why?  Did I miss something on craigslist on this?

The colors I've tried that don't work are as follows:

#FF0000
#FF9100
#FF4C01
#FFFF99
#FFCC00
#FF3399
#FF99CC
#FFE5F2
#E1CC81
#F7F4E7
#FF6666

Comment: What does _"will not render properly"_ mean?  Color is wrong, dithered, blank, or what?

Comment: What do you mean by they don't render properly? Can you show us an example?

Comment: I think this question belongs on Web Apps.

Comment: Despite your claim that they all include "F", #E1CC81 does not include any "F".

Comment: Try using the color names instead of the HEX values, e.g.: `{color:red;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check out the [CraigsList Help Page](http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/html_in_craigslist_postings/), it tells you that it only supports a select ten colors.

> (Supported colors: black, blue, fuchsia, green, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, teal.)